# Struggling using CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to use CefSharp and i coded a WinFormsApp. Here is my 'MainForm.cs'

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
namespace EmbededChrome
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
    Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser ("www.google.com");
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();
    }
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
}
```

When i run the app, it says:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or its integrated code or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> at EmbededChrome.MainForm.InitBrowser ()
>
> location: EmbededChrome.MainForm..ctor () c: \ Users \ AnaKu \ Documents \ SharpDevelop Projects \ EmbededChrome \ MainForm.cs: line 21
>
> location: EmbededChrome.Program.Main (String [] args) in c: \ Users \ HomeKu \ Documents \ SharpDevelop Projects \ EmbededChrome \ Program.cs: line 27

How can i fix it?

Comment: The reference to the dll is wrong or it doesn't exist.  You need the file CefSharp.Core.dll.  Check the path in the exception to see if the file exist.  You can search you machine for the file using windows explorer.  You may need to download the file from the web.  The location of the file is in the csproj and may need to be changed.

Comment: yeah i downloaded file from web added it using 'ad referrance'. I am 100% sure it exists on project because its viewable on 'referances'

Comment: can you put the dll in the bin folder and try again

Comment: @gauravsa i tried it. didnt work

Comment: Be sure to read [the faq](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Runtime_dependencies).

Comment: But it may not be accessible or in wrong folder.  Open the csproj with notepad and check to make sure it is in correct folder.   Not all dll files are the same.  Older dll before WinXP cannot be read by VS in c# and you need a c++ wrapped to run in c#.

Comment: Did you install CefSharp through Nuget?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a working example

Comment: @amaitland i could never figure out how to download a project from github and execute it. I have downloaded [this](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms) but i dont know how to execute it

Comment: Checkout the project using GitHub and then open in visual studio. Visual studio community 2017 or 2019 would be best.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have build configuration set to AnyCPU.

I've run into the similar exception, and simply switched to x86 to make it gone. You can try switching to x86 to see if that helps in your case. Configuring CefSharp to work properly for AnyCPU appears to be cumbersome, if possible at all.

Comment: It's possible and not particularly difficult. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample has a working example. For WinForms you need only add two lines https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/95/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L19 and https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/95/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms.csproj#L30